# How to create gmail business user account using google API with PHP

Tags: php, gmail, gmail-api, google-admin-sdk, google-directory-api

I want to create a new **gmail business user account** in gmail using PHP.  When I run this code it will shows some message like `Open the following link in your browser:` with URL and asking for verification code. If I run the link in browser it will generate some random string. I got **403 error** when I paste the random string in terminal for verification. Here is my code.

```
<?php
require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';


define('APPLICATION_NAME', 'Directory API PHP Quickstart');
define('CREDENTIALS_PATH', '~/.credentials/admin-directory_v1-php-quickstart.json');
define('CLIENT_SECRET_PATH', __DIR__ . '/client_secret.json');
// If modifying these scopes, delete your previously saved credentials
// at ~/.credentials/admin-directory_v1-php-quickstart.json
define('SCOPES', implode(' ', array(
  Google_Service_Directory::ADMIN_DIRECTORY_USER_READONLY)
));

if (php_sapi_name() != 'cli') {
  throw new Exception('This application must be run on the command line.');
}

/**
 * Returns an authorized API client.
 * @return Google_Client the authorized client object
 */
function getClient() {
  $client = new Google_Client();
  $client->setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME);
  $client->setScopes(SCOPES);
  $client->setAuthConfig(CLIENT_SECRET_PATH);
  $client->setAccessType('offline');

  // Load previously authorized credentials from a file.
  $credentialsPath = expandHomeDirectory(CREDENTIALS_PATH);
  if (file_exists($credentialsPath)) {
    $accessToken = json_decode(file_get_contents($credentialsPath), true);
  } else {
    // Request authorization from the user.
    $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
    printf("Open the following link in your browser:\n%s\n", $authUrl);
    print 'Enter verification code: ';
    $authCode = trim(fgets(STDIN));

    // Exchange authorization code for an access token.
    $accessToken = $client->fetchAccessTokenWithAuthCode($authCode);

    // Store the credentials to disk.
    if(!file_exists(dirname($credentialsPath))) {
      mkdir(dirname($credentialsPath), 0700, true);
    }
    file_put_contents($credentialsPath, json_encode($accessToken));
    printf("Credentials saved to %s\n", $credentialsPath);
  }
  $client->setAccessToken($accessToken);

  // Refresh the token if it's expired.
  if ($client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
    $client->fetchAccessTokenWithRefreshToken($client->getRefreshToken());
    file_put_contents($credentialsPath, json_encode($client->getAccessToken()));
  }
  return $client;
}
```

My error

> Fatal error: Uncaught Google_Service_Exception: { "error": { "errors": [ { "domain": "global", "reason": "forbidden", "message": "Not Authorized to access this resource/api" } ], "code": 403, "message": "Not Authorized to access this resource/api" } }

Comment: Welcome to stack please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.  Your question is to broad please show us what you have tried and describe any problems you are having with your current solution.

Comment: I have update my question.

Comment: Which 403 error please copy the full error into your question.

Comment: `Fatal error: Uncaught Google_Service_Exception: {
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "forbidden",
    "message": "Not Authorized to access this resource/api"
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "Not Authorized to access this resource/api"
 }
}`

Answer (score 0):

> Fatal error: Uncaught Google_Service_Exception:

```
{  
   "error":{  
      "errors":[  
         {  
            "domain":"global",
            "reason":"forbidden",
            "message":"Not Authorized to access this resource/api"
         }
      ],
      "code":403,
      "message":"Not Authorized to access this resource/api"
   }
}
```

Means that the user you are authenticating with does not have access to an admin directory account

> The Directory API lets you perform administrative operations on users, groups, organizational units, and devices in your account.

**Solution**: Login with a user who has access to the G suite account.

Comment: Its woking now. Is that a way to create a user account using PHP?